# How to get ONLY text from selected cells in Word table?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, vsto

I'm writing a VSTO that needs to get the selected text from an email and do stuff with it.  I found / modified some code that works great to get text from the body of an email IFF its plain text.  If the text is in a table, it only seems to return the first selected cell.  If I attempt to inspect the Application.Selection.Range.Cells, it returns a portion of the table, but includes cells that are selected and doesn't include all the cells.  Anyone know how to get the selected cells?  Here's the base code that works for getting selected text from a body of an email:

```
        Dim objExplorer As Outlook.Explorer = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer()

        'Get the current MailItem
        Dim mailItem As Outlook.MailItem = TryCast(objExplorer.Selection(1), Outlook.MailItem)

        'Get the current TaskItem
        Dim taskItem As Outlook.TaskItem = TryCast(objExplorer.Selection(1), Outlook.TaskItem)

        'Get current ContactItem
        Dim contactItem As Outlook.ContactItem = TryCast(objExplorer.Selection(1), Outlook.ContactItem)

        'Get the current AppointmentItem
        Dim appointmentItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem = TryCast(objExplorer.Selection(1), Outlook.AppointmentItem)

        Dim inspector As Outlook.Inspector = Nothing

        If (mailItem IsNot Nothing) Then
            'Obtain Inspector object for the current MailItem
            inspector = mailItem.GetInspector
        ElseIf (taskItem IsNot Nothing) Then
            'Obtain Inspector object for the current TaskItem
            inspector = taskItem.GetInspector
        ElseIf (contactItem IsNot Nothing) Then
            'Obtain Inspector object for the current NoteItem
            inspector = contactItem.GetInspector
        ElseIf (appointmentItem IsNot Nothing) Then
            'obtain Inspector object for the current AppointmentItem
            inspector = appointmentItem.GetInspector
        End If

        If inspector Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox("Please open an item to scan.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation)
            Return ""
        End If

        ' Obtain the Document object from the Inspector object
        Dim document As word.Document = inspector.WordEditor

        'Store the selected text to a variable
        Dim selectedText As String = If(document.Application.Selection IsNot Nothing, document.Application.Selection.Text, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

From the question

> Anyone know how to get the selected cells?

I understand the user will select multiple, non-contiguous cells in the expectation that their content can be read.

This is not possible; Word's object model can't handle multiple *selections*, even though the user can create them (since relatively recently, actually - the object model never caught up with that).

It will be necessary to apply some kind of unique character formatting to `Application.Selection` then locate each instance of that formatting in order to extract the content. Usually, that would be done using Find in a loop - the loop part to pick up the content and remove the formatting.

The code snippet below illustrates how this can be done.

- A "neutral" character style is added to the document. Since it's based on the default font for the current paragraph, it will not be visible to the user.
- This style is applied to the current selection. (`Selection` is the only part of the object model that can work with multiple, selected, non-contiguous content.)
- The entire body of the document is defined as the search range and the only search criterium is the neutral style
- The search is performed in a loop, as long as the style is found.
- The found content is appended to a string (or otherwise processed, as required), the default paragraph font style is re-applied to the found range. If the range is in a table cell, this needs to be applied to the entire cell.
- The range is then collapsed before the loop repeats.
- At the end, the marker style is deleted from the document.

  ```
  Dim doc As Word.Document = inspector.WordEditor
  Dim styl As Word.Style = doc.styles.Add("MultiSelectMarker", _
                           Word.WdStyleType.wdStyleTypeCharacter)
  styl.BaseStyle = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleDefaultParagraphFont
  Application.Selection.Style = styl

  Dim rngFind As Word.Range = doc.Content
  Dim selectedContent As String

  With rngFind.Find
      .Text = ""
      .Format = True
      .Style = styl
      .Wrap = Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindStop
      Do While .Execute
        'Concatenate the non-contiguous selections' content
        selectedContent = selectedContent & rngFind.Text & " "
        If rngFind.Information(Word.WdInformation.wdWithInTable) Then
          'Extend the range to include the cell structures so that
          'applying the default style does not result in Find.Execute = true
          rngFind.Cells(1).Range.Style = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleDefaultParagraphFont
        Else
          rngFind.Style = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleDefaultParagraphFont
        End If
        'Move outside the found Range so that the search continues
        rngFind.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      Loop
  End With
  Debug.Print(selectedContent)
  styl.Delete
  ```

Comment: thanks for the feedback.  This looks like a very clever solution.  I guess I should have stated that this is an Outlook VSTO, which relies on Word to process the text.  Think this will still work?  I'm wondering if Outlook will say the text is read only and thus I can't monkey around with the styles.  Thoughts?

Comment: Using Word as the Editor styles should be supported. Give it a try?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was backed up with other things.  I implemented the function as you sent.  Unfortunately, it barfed attempting to add a style.  It said "The method or property is not available because the document is locked for editing."  Dang.  This would probably work in Word, but maybe not in Outlook?  Any other ideas?

Comment: @Dan Are you able to use `Selection` to apply some weird kind of formatting that it's certain the user won't apply? In extremis, you can `Find` that and remove it as you go. It's not as elegant or fast, but ought to work...

Comment: I think not because this is actually in outlook, not word, so the content is read only.

Comment: @Dan Can you activate it for editing, as can be done in the Outlook UI? I don't see any other way to get at the user selection...